# Flex: Animate an image how to do it in as3

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, animation

i am having problems with animation. Can't realize how to animate things in flex?

E.g. in my current self made project I want to make am image to move after response from server. E.g. after event on client side is made, server returns coods of new location of an image. How do I animate the movement?

Examples will be appreciated,

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In mxml: http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/langref/mx/effects/Move.html#includeExamplesSummary
In as3: http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flash/articles/creating_animation_as3.html

Or is your question more about how to tie the animation to the server-side event?

Comment: Basically yes, I want to animate an image after response from server.

Comment: How are you calling the server?  Typically you would initiate the animation in your event handler that receives the data from the server.